# Why does $PV=nRT$ hold for adiabatic processes?

Tags: thermodynamics

In an adiabatic process, $PV^{\gamma}=\rm{constant}$. To find a relation between temperature and volume, we substitute $P = NRT/V$ instead of pressure $P$. Why can we do that?

Comment: Uh, just because one equation is true doesn't make another equation false. An ideal gas doing an adiabatic process is still an ideal gas.

Comment: Because, in the adiabatic process, the temperature is changing.

Comment: Why do you think we *can't* do that?

Answer (score 2):

The state equation includes three variables, the process equation includes two of them. As the number of equations is smaller than the number of variables, there is no contradiction between the equations.